# Volume of a solid of revolution, changing orientation

Tags: calculus, volume

I am having trouble getting through this problem, been working on it for quite some time and getting nowhere. The problem is as follows:

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the two curves about the y axis.

$$x = y-y^{2}$$ $$x=0$$

I changed the curves to the following(and rotating them about the x axis):

$$c(x) = x - x^2 $$
$$ y = 0 $$

I then set area equal to: $$A(x) = \pi (c(x))^2 $$
From here, shouldn't I be able to do the following to find the volume? If this is wrong, why is it wrong?

$$V = \int_0^1 A(x)dx\ $$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, if using $x$ instead of $y$ feels better, do it. (Geometrically, you are reflecting in the line $x=y$.) So, expanding, we want $\pi\int_0^1 (x^2-2x^3+x^4)\,dx$.

Comment: Gah, there must have been something wrong with my integration then... That did the trick! Thanks very much!

Comment: You are welcome. I expanded to make sure that nothing had gone wrong there. I think the answer is $\frac{\pi}{30}$, but my mental arithmetic is not entirely reliable, though better than when I use a calculator.